# Bootstrap popover changing position with resolution

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I have bootstrap popover as follows

```
<div style="float:left; width:30%"></div>
<div class="popover results" style="z-index:1060; float:left; width:70%">
     <div class="arrow"></div>
        <div class="popover-inner">
        <h3 class="popover-title"></h3>
        <div class="popover-content">
        <p></p>
    </div></div>
</div>
```

I saw that with change in screen resolution, its changing the relative position with the input element I have. I want to maintain the relative position of popover and input element same irrespective of resolution. Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Please, post your jsfiddle.

Comment: I would suggest making the popover relative to a parent, but frankly that is difficult to do when you don't have enough code to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening since I used following in above code

```
<div style="float:left; width:30%"></div>
```

I removed it and it now auto adjusts correctly